# what does second parameter now means in strtotime

Tags: php, datetime

What is the purpose of second parameter in [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function?

Based on the first `$time` parameter it returns
`Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC),`

Then how the second parameter affects the result?

Answer (score 4):

In the reference itself, it is written:

> The timestamp which is used as a base for the calculation of relative
>   dates.

Which means the second parameter will be taken as the base. For example, if you provide a base for the timestamp of yesterday, then the function will return the number of seconds elapsed from yesterday instead of January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC

For an example, lets run the following code (where 1514160000 is the timestamp of christmas 2017 i.e. 25'th of december 2017 at 00:00:00) :

```
$ts1 = strtotime("tomorrow", 1514160000);
echo "Date: " . date('Y-m-d', $ts1) . ", timestamp: " . $ts1 . "<br>";

$ts2 = strtotime("tomorrow");
echo "Date: " . date('Y-m-d', $ts2) . ", timestamp: " . $ts2 . "<br>";
```

which will print:

```
Date: 2017-12-26, timestamp: 1514246400
Date: 2018-08-08, timestamp: 1533686400
```

You can clearly see that, when I use the timestamp as the second parameter the function took it as the base and "tomorrow" resulted in the date as "2017-12-26" which is the next day of the given base timestamp. In the next example when I directly passed the "tomorrow" without any base it resulted into the next date from today.

I hope this clarifies the use of second parameter.

Comment: What is the effect if `$time` is set as `"10 September 2000"`?

Comment: If the first parameter i.e. `$time` is something absolute, then, in that case, the second parameter will be simply ignored.

Answer (score 2):

strtotime() can take relative dates as first parameter, like "+1 day".

In this use, the second parameter, $now, defines the reference to use. By default, it is the current timestamp, obtained by time().

For example :

```
strtotime("+1 day"); //1533719923, timestamp of tomorrow, 8 august 2018
strtotime("+1 day", 0); //86400, timestamp of 2 january 1970
```

Comment: So if `$time` is something absolute like `"10 September 2000"` then $now will have no effect?

Comment: Indeed. `strtotime("10 september 2000", time())` is the same as `strtotime("10 september 2000", 0)`, `strtotime("10 september 2000", 100000)` or just `strtotime("10 september 2000")`. The last is more readable, tough.

Answer (score 0):

https://3v4l.org/8pAMk

```
echo strtotime("+1 day");
echo strtotime("+1 day", null);
echo strtotime("+1 day", 0);
echo strtotime("+1 day", time());
```

```
8.0~
1691143883
1691143883
86400
1691143883
```

```
5.x-7.4
1691143883
86400
86400
1691143883
```